# jquery add one example

Tags: jquery, css

this is kind of specific but i know someone can help me. i'm trying to tighten up my code by not having to repeat this jquery fuction 20 times. Each of these divs (#person1, #person2, etc...) will keep going up till about 25. Is there a way for jquery to dynamically add 1 and thus replace my seperate functions with just one to "call out" to #person1, #person2, #person3, #person16, etc.? Have i been clear enough in what i'm trying to acheive?

Likewise, is my css syntax clumsy? is there a beter way to write it? Again i'll need to display about 25 individuals on this page... my working example of what i'm tryin to do can be found [here](http://www.sawtoothgroup.com/ourpeople_new.html)

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#person1-trigger, #person1").on("mouseenter", function() {
            $("#person1").show();
      }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $("#person1").hide();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#person2-trigger, #person2").on("mouseenter", function() {
            $("#person2").show();
      }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $("#person2").hide();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#person3-trigger, #person3").on("mouseenter", function() {
            $("#person3").show();
      }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $("#person3").hide();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#person4-trigger, #person4").on("mouseenter", function() {
            $("#person4").show();
      }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $("#person4").hide();
      });
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    #person1-container, #person3-container {
    float:left;
    }

    #person2-container, #person4-container {
    float:left;
    margin-left:460px;
    }

    #person1-trigger, #person2-trigger {
    height: 345px;
    width: 460px;
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    }

    #person1, #person2 {
    height:305px;
    width: 420px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:80;
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    display: none;
    padding:20px;
    }

    #person3-trigger, #person4-trigger {
    height: 345px;
    width: 460px;
    position:absolute;
    top:745px;
    }

    #person3, #person4 {
    height:305px;
    width: 420px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:80;
    position:absolute;
    top:745px;
    display: none;
    padding:20px;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML snippet

```
<div id="person1-container">
    <div id="person1-trigger"><img src="images/james_noebels.jpg" width="460" height="345"></div>
    <div id="person1"><h1>James Noebels</h1>Junior Copywriter<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus dictum ex a venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla tristique arcu et orci consequat, eget feugiat ex placerat. Praesent convallis erat id ipsum feugiat egestas. Pellentesque gravida ultrices molestie. Nam quis tristique dui. In malesuada eget orci id aliquam. Integer tortor mauris, tincidunt eu sodales finibus, semper vitae leo.</div>
</div>

<div id="person2-container">
    <div id="person2-trigger"><img src="images/susan_morrisey.jpg" width="460" height="345"></div>
    <div id="person2"><h1>Susan Morrisey</h1>Account Executive<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus dictum ex a venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla tristique arcu et orci consequat, eget feugiat ex placerat. Praesent convallis erat id ipsum feugiat egestas. Pellentesque gravida ultrices molestie. Nam quis tristique dui. In malesuada eget orci id aliquam. Integer tortor mauris, tincidunt eu sodales finibus, semper vitae leo.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you gave everything classes it would reduce your code to this -

```
$(".person").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).find('.details').show(); 
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).find('.details').hide();
  });
});
```

Then it wouldn't matter how many `persons` you added to the page.

For your current markup you can do this - [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k1703r9e/)

```
$('[id$="container"]').on("mouseenter", function () { // mouseenter on the container
    var personParts = $(this).attr('id').split('-'); // find which person this is
    var thisPerson = personParts[0]; // see Ma? No hands!
    $(this).find('#' + thisPerson).show(); 
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var personParts = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    var thisPerson = personParts[0];
    $(this).find('#' + thisPerson).hide();
});
```

This will work as well as fixing the classes and doesn't require that you change anything about how you're working now. It is *a little* more overhead, but you shouldn't have a problem given the size of what you're planning to do now.

Comment: in theory Jay this looks right to me. have you see the added HTML snippet to confirm that this approach will be effective?

Comment: I updated my answer to work with your current markup @user2371115

Comment: brilliant Jay! it's working perfectly. any thoughts on my css markup? would it just be smart to stick with the way i'm working based on this smallish scale?

Answer (score 0):

You can user the following syntax:

Declare a variable with a number

```
var count = 1;
```

Then use the following logic to create the selectors:

```
$("#person"+ count).show();
```

to repeat the process you only need to increase the count.
Hope it helps

UPDATE:

```
for (i = 1; i < 25; i++) { 
    var person = "#person" + i;
    $(person + "-trigger, " + person).on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(person).show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(person).hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: you need to elaborate a little more for me. like quite literally retype out the entire function if possible? many thanks for your quick response...

Comment: I updated my code. Does it work? your idea is to repeat the "person" selector like person1, person2, person3, etc. Am I right? If not, try to provide a jsfiddle base example with what you have done so far. Without it people don't know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, jquery can create a 'set' of targets in a selector object and use any kind of function on them

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/0f7L7jL0/

Code:

```
var theDivs = $('.class01,.class02');

theDivs.on("mouseenter", function() {
       $(this).html('entered!');
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).html('Left!');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)s to make this happen using your existing HTML.

Loop all control IDs that start with "person" and end with "-trigger" using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/). You now have the index of the control and you can add your events as desired. You will need to create a closure so you have access to the control name.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id^='person'][id$='-trigger']").each(function(index) {
    var controlName = "#person" + (index + 1);
    $(controlName + ", " + controlName + "-trigger").on("mouseenter", function() {
      handleMouseEventClosure(controlName, true);
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
      handleMouseEventClosure(controlName, false);
    });
  });
});

function handleMouseEventClosure(controlName, show) {
  if (show)
    $(controlName).show();
  else
    $(controlName).hide();
}
```

```css
.target {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a id="person1-trigger" href="">Person 1 Trigger</a>
  <div id="person1" class="target"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <a id="person2-trigger" href="">Person 2 Trigger</a>
  <div id="person2" class="target"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <a id="person3-trigger" href="">Person 3 Trigger</a>
  <div id="person3" class="target"></div>
</div>
```